# Why does Visual Studio prompt error in XAML when I use Label?

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012

I use Visual Studio 2012, and wrote some XAML(of WPF) code, just like this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Label Target="txt">UserName:</Label>
    <TextBox Name="txt"></TextBox>
</StackPanel>
```

then, the compilation failed. It said to **Label related-code**,

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: context.

I don't know its meaning. Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a designer-only error. Code should compile without any issue.

**EDIT:** This exception is due to Silverlight not supporting this syntax : `Target="txt"`. this syntax is only supported by WPF. It's a known bug in the designer, even if your project is a WPF project, and was caused by MS wanting to support design-time checks for Silverlight.

If you don't want the exception you have to use the full binding syntax (supported by WPF and Silverlight)

```
<Label Target="{Binding ElementName=txt}">UserName:</Label>
```